# How to solve $\frac {365!} {365^{x+1}}\cdot\sum\limits_{i=0}^x \frac i {(364-i)!} \ge 1$

Tags: inequality, numerical-methods

Trying to see where $f(x) = \frac {365!} {365^{x+1}}\cdot\sum\limits_{i=0}^x \frac i {(364-i)!}$ becomes more or equals one. But I can't simplify the equation any further and all programming languages I use return stackoverflows. Any ideas?

I guess someone owning Wolfram Alpha Pro should be able to compute it with:

```
 (365!/365^(x+1))*(sum j/(364-j)!), j=0 to x)
```

Comment: Have you tried investigating what happens with smaller numbers (e.g., drop the "36" from "365" and "364"), to see if there is a pattern?

Comment: Try $x=1$ and then $x=2$

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)={365!\over365^{x+1}}\sum_{i=0}^x{i\over(364-i)!}={1\over365^{x}}\sum_{i=1}^xi{364!\over(364-i)!}={1\over365^x}(364+2\cdot364\cdot363+\cdots)$$

For $x=2$ we have $2\cdot364\cdot363\gt365^2$, so $f(x)\gt1$.

Comment: Interesting is the fact that $f(x)>1$ only if $2\leq x\leq 51$ (there is a miximum value for $x=19$. . Do you think that we could prove it ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, if the question is to find the *range* of $x$ for which $f(x)\ge1$, I think I'd definitely do some small-number experimenting (as I suggested in my comment below the OP).  I read the OP's "becomes" as meaning just the first value.  BTW, I like the word "miximum"!

Comment: Funny typo, indeed ! I am just wondering how the behaviour of this function could be "predicted". Interesting problem, I think (but I am stuck). Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, agreed, on all counts!

Comment: Something funny (I hope) : $f(p,x_*)$ is "almost" a linear function of $x_*=\lfloor\sqrt p\rfloor$

Answer (score 0):

Interested by the post, I considered (just as Barry Cipra did in his answer)$$f(p,x)=\frac{(p+1)!}{ (p+1)^{x+1}}\sum\limits_{i=0}^x \frac i {(p-i)!}=\frac{1}{ (p+1)^{x}}\sum\limits_{i=0}^x i\frac {p!} {(p-i)!}$$ And we can notice $$f(p,0)=0 \qquad f(p,1)=\frac{p}{p+1}<1\qquad $$ For a given value of $p$, it exists an $x_-$ such that $f(p,x_-) >1$ but it also exists an $x_*$ such that $p(x_*)$ is maximum and it also exists another larger value  $x_+$ such that $f(p,x_+)$ become smaller than $1$ again.

I have not been able to prove all the above and the results given below are just results from simulation.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  p & x_* &x_+ \\
 50 & 7 &16 \\
 100 &10& 24 \\
 150 &12 & 31 \\
 200 &14 &37 \\
 250 &15 & 42 \\
 300 &17 & 47 \\
 350 &18 & 51 \\
 400 &20 & 55 \\
 450 &21 & 59 \\
 500 &22 & 63
\end{array}
\right)$$

For all considered values, $f(p,2)>1$.

What is interesting to notice is that the maximum value of $f(p,x)$ is never very large and a "careful" coding of the summation (basically doing as Barry Cipra) should avoid overflows.

Comment: Can you redo your calculation of $x_*$ for $p=150$?  WA gave me $f(150,13)\approx7.03$ while $f(150,12)\approx7.09$ (with $f(150,11)\approx7.06$ to round things out).  I tested $p=150$ because I noticed that $x_*\le\sqrt p$ in all other cases.

Comment: @BarryCipra. Sorry for the delay ! You are perfectly correct. I edited my numbers. Cheers.

Comment: Super!  Considering in particular the results for $p=100$ and $400$, what do you suppose are the odds that $x_*=\lfloor\sqrt p\rfloor$ is an exact formula?

Comment: @BarryCipra. It seems that this is very correct !  I checked up to $p=10^4$ and it is always true. Very good catch, for sure. Now the big question : how to prove it ? In any manner, be sure it was my pleasure to work this with you (you did almost all the work). Cheers and thanks.

Comment: My pleasure as well (although all I did, really, was to question an apparent exception to a pattern).  I agree, it'd be nice to have a proof!